# MySQL performance (INT, DECIMAL, VARCHAR)

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I'm designing a token based user acess system, and I got what it seems a tricky question.

Tokens will be enought big to achive

```
Size = logged-users*(1/break-effort)*RUID-space
```

Estimated 16 bytes. Those tokens should be stored inside a mySQL database.

I can transmit them trought POST:

- decimal (39 bytes)
- hex-encoded (32 bytes)
- 62based (a-zA-Z0-9) (22 bytes)

Now supposing conversion times irrelevant, which should be the data type (indexed column) that would give best search performances?

- DECIMAL(39,0)
- VARCHAR(22)
- two BIGINT (first indexed second not)

Comment: You can do a performance-test for that

Comment: I will, but there is allways something that in a controlled environment can work but there would be future considerations to do, like full RAM because of many indexes or different search approaches that someone on a run-in system may had experienced.

Answer (score 0):

[image: MySQL performance test]

This is what i found out.
VARCHAR is in any case the worst for SELECT WHERE.

Comment: You probably should have been using `VARBINARY` rather than `VARCHAR` if your data is case-sensitive.

Comment: I did, but BINARY benchmarks are worst than VARCHAR, only in MyISAM are a bit better!